# How to get the channel of a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to get the channel of a message send by an user, I have that

```
client.on('message', msg => {
```

But I don't how to get the channel, how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `msg` object returned follows the [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message) format you can find in the Discord.js documentation.

Hence, you can get the channel the message was sent on by `msg.channel`, and its name `msg.channel.name`.

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly what I wanted to do ^^